# Redirection problems with SpringBoot, Nginx and Spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, nginx, spring-security

I am having a problem with Spring boot and nginx in terms of redirection, I have the following path "www.dental-admin.test/back-dental-admin/microlens-service/swagger-ui.html" the part of "/back-dental-admin/" makes nginx redirect the traffic to localhost:8080 where I have spring cloud gateway and then the part of "/microlens-service/" is responsible for redirecting the gateway to the corresponding microservice, the thing is that when I try to consume "www. dental-admin.test/back-dental-admin/microlens-service/swagger-ui.html" I am redirected to "www.dental-admin.test/back-dental-admin/microlens-service/login" which is normal because I have spring security but the thing is that when I hit the login button I am redirected to "www. dental-admin.test/microlens-service/login" i.e. "/back-dental-admin/" disappears. I have tried to use "forward-headers-strategy: framework" along with some configurations in nginx, but the only thing I get is that when I use "www.dental-admin.test/back-dental-admin/microlens-service/swagger-ui.html" I am redirected to "www.dental-admin. test/back-dental-admin/back-dental-admin/microlens-service/login" that is to say it duplicates the "/back-dental-admin/" and the strange thing is that it is not even clicking on login it is directly in the prime redirection. I will leave the configuration files of nginx, spring gateway, and the micro service to help me to identify what could be happening to me.

this is the nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name www.dental-admin.test;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/dental-admin.test+1.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/dental-admin.test+1-key.pem;

    location / {

        proxy_set_header Forwarded $http_forwarded;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location /back-dental-admin/ {

        proxy_set_header Forwarded $http_forwarded;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix /back-dental-admin/;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    }
}
```

the spring gateway conf

```
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  application:
    zipkin: http://localhost:9411
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "https://www.dental-admin.test/"
            allowedHeaders: "*"
            allowedMethods: "*"
            allowCredentials: true
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
      routes:
        - id: auth-service-route
          uri: lb://auth-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/auth-service/**
          filters:
            - AuthFilter
            - RewritePath=/auth-service/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
        - id: client-service-route
          uri: lb://client-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/client-service/**
          filters:
            - AuthFilter
            - RewritePath=/client-service/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
        - id: user-service-route
          uri: lb://user-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/user-service/**
          filters:
            - AuthFilter
            - RewritePath=/user-service/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}    
        - id: microlens-service-route
          uri: lb://microlens-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/microlens-service/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/microlens-service/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
```

and the microservice conf

```
server:
  port: ${PORT:${SERVER_PORT:0}}
  forward-headers-strategy: framework
spring:
  application:
    zipkin: http://localhost:9411
eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    service-url:
      default-zone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
  instance:
    instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${vcap.application.instance_id:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on configuration files, I think your nginx configuration and Spring Cloud Gateway configuration are both properly set up forward headers. There may be an issue with your microservice configuration.

In microservice configuration file, you have set the `forward-headers-strategy` to framework. It means that Spring use its default forwarding strategy for headers.
However, this may not be enough for your specific scenario. You may need to configure additional headers to be forwarded, such as the `X-Forwarded-Prefix` header that you are setting in your nginx configuration.

Maybe you can define a custom `ForwardedHeaderTransformer` bean in your microservice configuration file. For example, the following [Link](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/classes/org.springframework.web.server.adapter.ForwardedHeaderTransformer) is a good reference to sets up a transformer that forwards the `X-Forwarded-Prefix` header.

I solved this problem with code like that:

```
@Bean
public ForwardedHeaderTransformer forwardedHeaderTransformer() {
    return new ForwardedHeaderTransformer() {
        @Override
        public HttpHeaders apply(HttpHeaders headers) {
            HttpHeaders transformed = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.forEach((key, values) -> {
                if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("X-Forwarded-Prefix")) {
                    transformed.addAll(key, values);
                }
                // add any other headers you need to forward here
            });
            return transformed;
        }
    };
}
```